# Android app: Another youtube url does not load video

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, initialization, android-youtube-api

When I first call this method I get loaded youtube video. But the second time when I call the method, my old youtube video remains. It looks like it does not initialize again.

```
private void showRoomInformations(final RoomDTO room){
    //Verify if the number of connections is the same
    if (room != null){
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;
        YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener mPlayerStateChangeListener;
        YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;

        mRoomDTO = room;
        TextView roomDescription = (TextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        TextView textRoomName = (TextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.textRoomName);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.view_youtube);

        textRoomName.setText(room.getName());
        roomDescription.setText(room.getDescription());

        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Done initializing.");

                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getYouTubeUrl(room.getMedia()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Failed to initialize.");
            }
        };
        mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YouTubeConfig.getApiKey(), mOnInitializedListener);
    }
}

private String getYouTubeUrl(String youTubeUrl){
    return youTubeUrl.replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
How to initialize YouTubePlayer again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the player only once. After that you should use `YouTubePlayer.loadVideo()` or `YouTubePlayer.cueVideo()`.